# How connect to MediaPlayer on android using php file

Tags: php, android, http

Last time I started using MediaPlayer in android app. I want to connect file to the server using php and play mp3 file. When I try to connect to a php file I get the error:

```
W/System.err:     at android.media.MediaPlayer._prepare(Native Method)
at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(MediaPlayer.java:1458)
at com.example.myApp.main_page.main_page.onCreate(main_page.java:41)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7963)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7952)
W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1307)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3629)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3806)
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2267)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8167)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:496)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1100)
```

My android activity code :

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
String ip = "http://myIp:80/rec.php";
try {
    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(ip);
    mediaPlayer.prepare();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
mediaPlayer.start();
```

My php code :

```
<?php
$file = 'directory/file.mp3';
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.android.package-archive');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.mp3');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
ob_clean();
echo readfile($file)
?>
```

When I connect to a php file with my browser download of file the starts.

Answer (score 0):

You should try [ExoPlayer](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer)

There was [discussion](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/5220) in ExoPlayer issue tracker.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. To improve your answers, please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Please consider providing an example how to use. Links should only be posted as a reference, not as a stand alone answer, as they can get obsolete.